# NSTableRowView not calling DrawBackground correctly during drag-drop operations

Tags: swift, macos, xamarin

I have an NSTableView with a set of rows. There are two types of rows - titles and data - which are displayed differently.

I am dragging an object from within my app onto the data rows. Drag and drop works fully and only data rows accept the drop - but there is a display issue.

I am using a custom NSTableRowView, and what I expect to see is that if I drag my object over a data row, then `DrawDraggingDestinationFeedback` should be called (it is) to draw my custom background used during drag operations. If I then drag my object out of the data row, I expect `DrawBackground` to be called (it is SOMETIMES) to redraw my standard background.

Heres the detail:

If I drag my object onto a data row and then completely away from the NSTableView, `DrawDraggingDestinationFeedback` is called on entry and `DrawBackground` is called on exit.

If I drag my object onto a row, and then *down* to the next row, 
`DrawDraggingDestinationFeedback` is called for the top row, then when I move down  `DrawDraggingDestinationFeedback` is called for the lower row, but `DrawBackground` is *not* called for the first row (i.e. its background color is not reset). This leaves BOTH rows looking like they are active drop destinations.

Weirdly, the final `DrawBackground` on exiting the table is called.

[image: Showing missing calls to DrawDraggingDestinationFeedback]

Here is my custom NSTableRowView:

```
       public class CustomSelectionRowView : NSTableRowView
    {
        /// The log object
        private static Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        private string type;
        private DataItem ditem;

        public CustomSelectionRowView(string type, DataItem ditem = null) : base()
        {
            this.type = type;
            this.ditem = ditem;
            DraggingDestinationFeedbackStyle = NSTableViewDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyle.Regular;
            SelectionHighlightStyle = NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyle.Regular;
        }
public override void DrawDraggingDestinationFeedback(CGRect dirtyRect)
        {
            log.Debug(ditem.title);
            if (type == "Data")
            {
                //  This can accept a drag-drop
                var color = NSColor.Gray;
                var p = NSGraphicsContext.CurrentContext.GraphicsPort;
                p.SetFillColor(color.CGColor);
                p.FillRect(dirtyRect);
            }
            else
                base.DrawDraggingDestinationFeedback(dirtyRect);
        }

        public override void DrawBackground(CGRect dirtyRect)
        {
            log.Debug(ditem.title);
            if (type == "Data")
            {
                //  We definitely have a Data block
                var color = NSColor.FromName("MainPaneDataBackground");
                var p = NSGraphicsContext.CurrentContext.GraphicsPort;
                p.SetFillColor(color.CGColor);
                p.FillRect(dirtyRect);

            }

            else 
                base.DrawBackground(dirtyRect);

        }
   }
```

Anyone have any ideas of how to work around this?
Many thanks.

[p.s. note that while my code here is C#/Xamarin... any swift help would be gratefully accepted - I speak both]

Comment: Hi , if set the `allowsMultipleSelection` for `NSTableVIew` be false , whehter it works ?

Comment: Excellent thought! Multiple Selection is already off (a core piece of functionality is that only one item in the list can be chosen at once). Also... small clarification - this is an NSOutlineView rather than NSTableView (outline view is subclass of tableview). Thanks.

Comment: Okey ,not sure swift also will occur this, better need to check whether it shows the same phenomenon in xcode .

Comment: It does seem like a fundamental flaw... I'll give it a try in Xcode.

Comment: That's fine , no mattter what result is . Remember to update news here :-)